# Angular: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' (NOT a repeat)

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngmodel

I have read many posts here in this same topic, but I am 99% sure I have complied with all the answers.
Starting with the very basic app that ng new  creates for you.  It runs fine, it passes the 3 Karma tests fine.
I add one new component with one input <==> typescript link using ngModel and it fails to test the new component with this error:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<div class="boxed">
    <b>Invoice:</b>
      <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]= "qty">
    </div>
 "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CalculateComponent.html@2:11
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<div class="boxed">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
    <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]= "qty">
</div>
 "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CalculateComponent.html@2:11
    at syntaxError (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1275:17)
    at TemplateParser.parse (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:15084:19)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24272:37)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24259:23)
    at eval (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24202:62)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24202:19)
    at eval (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24120:19)
    at Object.then (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1266:77)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24118:26)
```

I have done the 
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
and  imports: [ FormsModule ]
and I have spelled ngModel correctly.   I will post the files next.

Help please.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CalculateComponent } from './calculate/calculate.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CalculateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**  Two versions, one with and one without the forms stuff. Don't think it is supposed to be there, but gave it a try too.
**Version 1:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testKarma';
}
```

**V2**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
   ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testKarma';
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CalculateComponent } from './calculate/calculate.component';  //klf
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CalculateComponent  
      ],
      imports: [ FormsModule ] 
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  it(`should have as title 'testKarma'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('testKarma');
  }));
  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to testKarma!');
  }));
});
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<div>
  <app-calculate></app-calculate>  
</div>
```

**calculate.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculate',
  templateUrl: './calculate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculate.component.css']
})
export class CalculateComponent implements OnInit {

  qty = 0;  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**calculate.component.html**

```
<div class="boxed">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
    <input [(ngModel)]= "qty">
</div>
```

**calculate.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CalculateComponent } from './calculate.component';

describe('CalculateComponent', () => {
  let component: CalculateComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CalculateComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CalculateComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CalculateComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you imported FormsModule in your calculate.component.spec.ts

Comment: @itsundefined If test has nothing to do with it why we can see `ng:///DynamicTestModule/CalculateComponent.html@2:11` in the error message? AFAIK, `DynamicTestModule` is created by TestBed

Answer (score 0):

#### Original thoughts:

There are a few issues I see.  Is this code working outside of the test?  First, there is a space after `ngModel` in calculate.component.html.  It currently is `[(ngModel)]= "qty"` but should be `[(ngModel)]="qty"`

Second, I believe you need to specify the 'name' attribute as well.  You have imported the FormsModule but you must add the name attribute for input with the same name in [(ngModel)].  So in your case your calculate.component.html would look something like:

```
<div class="boxed">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
    <input [(ngModel)]="qty" name="qty">
</div>
```

You may want to specify a type as well, for example `type="text"`.

*(These original thoughts were NOT the source of your issue)*

### Update with Stackblitz

Now I have copied your code into a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53437297?file=app%2Fcalculate.component.spec.ts).  Since you are trying to test the CalculateComponent I simplified quite a bit by eliminating the app component entirely from this testing environment and just setting up a simple TestWrapperComponent that acts in the same capacity - it provides the environment for CalculateComponent to execute in.  I then get a reference to CalculateComponent from within TestWrapperComponent and can test things on it, such as the value of the 'qty' variable, etc.  See the Stackblitz for details.

I set it up this way to unit test the CalculateComponent separate and apart from AppComponent.  Good discussion on the differences between unit, integration and e2e testing [here](https://medium.com/pacroy/separate-unit-integration-and-functional-tests-for-continuous-delivery-f4dc240d8f2f).

To reproduce your error, all I have to do is comment out the import of `FormsModule` in `calculate.component.spec.ts`, like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ /* FormsModule */ ],
    declarations: [ 
        TestWrapperComponent,
        CalculateComponent
    ]
}).compileComponents();
```

> **NOTE**: When `FormsModule` is imported properly into the TestBed, then the component creates and tests without error.  Be sure this is imported properly into the TestBed in `calculate.component.spec.ts`, *not simply into the one in* `app.component.spec.ts`!

Comment: I did run app.component.ts with and without the Forms, that does not help.

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="qty" name="qty">  this does not fix it.  (removing the space and adding the name=      And yes, it the app works.  Its part of a bigger app that works, I just stripped it done to this to elminate as many variables as possible.

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="qty" name="qty" type="text">  does not help.

Comment: stripped the html down to just this   <div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="qty" name="qty" type="text">
</div>

Comment: running with Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect , @angular-devkit/build-angular, 
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer, @angular-devkit/build-webpack 
@angular-devkit/core, @angular-devkit/schematics   all  Ver  0.8.7
@angular/cli          6.2.7
@ngtools/webpack   6.2.7
@schematics/angular   0.8.7
@schematics/update     0.8.7
rxjs        6.2.2
typescript    2.9.2
webpack    4.16.4

Comment: Indeed, this is interesting.  Perhaps put it in a Stackblitz, to see it in action with all the needed pieces.  Feel free to fork this one and edit with your data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53122846?file=app%2Femployee.component.spec.ts

Comment: I don't know how to fork, or even what the implications are, but I did go tp stackblitz and create my app there, which is running.  This one has a bit more function in the calculate component than the code I posted above.  But still super simple.  The app runs correctly, but I don't know how to do ng test in that environemnt?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhuwfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcalculate%2Fcalculate.component.css

Comment: That’s why I sent you a link to MY Stackblitz.  Go to that link and you will see at the top of the page the option to fork this project.  That makes a copy of it in your own environment so you can edit it and put in your own information. The reason I offered to do it this way is the Jasmine testing environment is already all set up in my Stackblitz, so if you fork it then it will be all set up in yours as well.

Comment: thanks.  I was afraid I was overwriting your code.  Later tonite I will figure out how to enable my site for jasmine, I might as well have this working for the long run.  thanks!

Comment: Seached webm couldn't find anything about jasmime on stackblitz, nothing in their doc.  Tried cloning the files and changes from your project, could to complicated and my chances of getting it right kept dropping and dropping.

Comment: Maybe a kind soul will download my project from github and explain my problem?   https://github.com/kurtfriedrichhotmail/testKarma

Comment: @kurtfriedrich - I have updated my answer above by copying your code into a working test environment in Stackblitz and showing where your error likely is.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for putting all that effort into this.  I guess in the run time environment somehow my calculate component was inheriting the Forms from my adding it to my app.component, probably becuase my calculate is embedded in the app, but in the test environment, that does not happen, which of course now makes sense, as the test run in isolation.   Again, you put in a lot of effort on this, I'll try and pass it on someday.

Comment: @kurtfriedrich - you’re welcome.  You can also upvote the answer if it was helpful.  :)

Comment: I did, but as my reputation is not high enough, it does not register.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I upvoted your question so that will help a bit.  Won't take long to get to 15 rep pts.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Short version of answer that @dmcgrandle figured out for me. (THANKS!!)

My primary component, app.component.html, includes a dependent compenent

```
<app-calculate></app-calculate>
```

I had added these needed line for ngModel to work in app.component.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
   ]
})
```

When I run the app, the calculate component was inheriting the Forms from my adding it to my app.component, and it worked just fine.  But when I ran ng test, it would fail, as the tests run in isolation, so then the calculate component could not use ngModel.  The fix was to include the Forms in the calculate.component.spec.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
...
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],  
      declarations: [ CalculateComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```